# What's the benefit of declaring class functions separately from their actual functionality?

Tags: c++, c, oop, function, class

In C++, what's the benefit of having a class with functions...

say

```
class someClass{
 public:
  void someFunc(int arg1);
};
```

then having the function's actual functionality declared after int main

```
int main() 
    { return 0; }

void someClass::someFunc(int arg1)
    {   cout<<arg1; }
```

Furthermore, what's the benefit of declaring the class in a .h header file, then putting the functionality in a .cpp file that #includes the .h file?

Comment: When you have a program with over 10 lines you'll be glad you've got your classes in separate files to you `main()` function.

Comment: BTW, common convention is to have at least 3 files:  class header, class definition and main.  The class header contains the class declaration (so other translation units can include it).  The class definition file contains the implementation of the class.  The main file contains functions related to the main application.  By having the class files separated from the main program, allows their re-use by other code with minimal alterations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dependency management. Users of the class only need to include the header file, so they don't depend on the implementation.

Another use is breaking circular dependencies.

Both issues may look like a waste of time with toy programs, but they start to grow into a really bad problem as the program grows.

Comment: For an example see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-circular-dependencies-in-c

Comment: Dependency management even becomes critical for programs spanning a few hundreds of thousands of lines. You don't want to recompile the whole thing when someone changes a comment :/